# How can i hit the controller using Partial View form that have different form type(ajax and begin form)

Tags: c#, razor, partial-views, ajaxform, html.beginform

I have a main form which is rendering a div to a partial view. I loads the controlls very fine. On main form
i have a controller which got a function that must get data from the partial view form, when i click the button
on partial view,it does not hit the controller(SaveSMRNotesFile).

When i click upload button from the partial view, it goes to SearchUploadNotes controller if i put the break point and that's not the one i want.

**How can i pass the data to a controller using partial view?**

**Main Form**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchUploadNotes", "UploadNotes", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "dvUploadNotes" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{

<div id="divControlls">
     @{Html.RenderPartial("_UploadNotesControllsGridPartialV", new TTAF.Portal.Parts.Web.Models.UploadNotesFolder.UploadNotesViewModel());}
</div>


<button class="btn btn-primary " id="btnSearch" name="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
 }
```

**Partial View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveSMRNotesFile", "UploadNotes", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal" , @id = "form-id", role = "form" }))
{
<button class="btn btn-primary " id="btnn" name="submit" type="sumbit" onclick="">Upload</button>
}
```

**Controller function**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SaveSMRNotesFile(UploadNotesViewModel mymodel)
 {
 }
```

Comment: nested forms should not be in the html

Comment: then how do i pass my functions to the controller or make communication with the controller.

Comment: It seems you want to upload the file to server via AJAX and then save the notes via a main form. I would recommend to use FormData and post the file via AJAX. Remove <form> from your partial view. Let me know if you need code for that

Comment: @KD can you show me by editing my code?

Comment: I think your approach is incorrect. Your main has a form, and your partial which is render in it, has another one. So, finally you are render one form inside other. You could try to render just one form and use formaction attribute for decide what method you will use in the controller.

Comment: @EliasMP can you please show me how i can do it by correcting my code so that i can learn from it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach for your problem could be:

**Main Form**

```
**@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchUploadNotes", "UploadNotes", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "dvUploadNotes" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{

@if(ViewBag.Control){
    <div id="divControlls">
         @{Html.RenderPartial("_UploadNotesControllsGridPartialV", new TTAF.Portal.Parts.Web.Models.UploadNotesFolder.UploadNotesViewModel());}
    </div>
    }

<input class="btn btn-primary " id="btnSearch" value="Search" type="submit" formaction="SearchUploadNotes">
 }
```

**Partial View**

```
<!-- RENDER YOUR DIFFERENT DATA AFTER YOUR SEARCH -->

    <input class="btn btn-primary " id="btnn" value="Upload" type="sumbit" formaction="SaveSMRNotesFile"/>
```

**Controller function**

```
    [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult SaveSMRNotesFile(UploadNotesViewModel mymodel)
     {
// DO YOUR STUFF COMING FROM THE DATA RECOVERED OF YOUR FORM IN A UploadNotesViewModel OBJECT
     }
    [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult SearchUploadNotes(UploadNotesViewModel mymodel)
     {
    // DO YOUR STUFF COMING FROM THE DATA RECOVERED OF YOUR FORM IN A UploadNotesViewModel OBJECT. RETURNS YOUR DATA AFTER THE SEARCH AND RETURN A VIEWDATA.CONTROL BOOL FOR RENDERING YOUR PARTIAL.
     }
```

The idea, as far as I got from your post (sorry for my english :)) is:

You will render just a form with search submit button, if it is clicked, you will render your partial, by ViewData.Control value, with the data searched plus a new submit button for uploading.

This button call, in the same controller but another method, defined for formaction attribute, called SaveSMRNotesFile, and it will do your stuff. I guess upload the new values for this data.

Hoping it helps. Let me know any doubt. Cheers mate.

Comment: what is @if(ViewBag.Control) is what? is it controller name?

Comment: Not, is a small container for data which you can send from your controller instead of passing data using the model. There are three types of it. ViewData, ViewBag and tempdata. They are used for this kind of purpouse... Check google mate... ;)

Comment: By the way, may you reward my efford and rate my answer? Cheers mate :)

Comment: Happy to help you mate. Happy coding :)